# .net Access Forms authentication "timeout" value in code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm adding a logout expiration alert to my application and would like to access my web.config forms authentication "timeout" value from my code.  Any way i could do this?

Answer (score 19):

I think you can read it from the FormsAuthentication static class methods, which would be better than doing it by reading the web.config directly as you may be inheriting authentication settings from a higher level web.config.

```
var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(user.EmailAddress, true, (int)FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes);
```

Comment: This is the best answer, but the Timeout property is only available on the FormsAuthentication static class in .Net 4.0 and higher.

Answer (score 7):

You can access the web.config's `timeout` value in:

`FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes`

I don't know since when it's available, I'm using .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 4):

```
 Configuration conn = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("");

            AuthenticationSection section = (AuthenticationSection)conn.SectionGroups.Get("system.web").Sections.Get("authentication");



            long cookieExpires = System.Convert.ToInt64(section.Forms.Timeout.TotalMinutes);
```

Comment: To get your current project's Web.Config path, type `Request.ApplicationPath` inside `OpenWebConfiguration("")`

Answer (score 1):

You can access it from your Javascript using the following:

```
var expireTime = <%= FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes %>;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [parse it directly from the web.config](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AccessingTheASPNETFormsAuthenticationTimeoutValue.aspx) file.

Answer (score 0):

This Code will give you `timeout` in minutes from `AuthenticationSection` section present in your current project's Web.Config file,

```
Configuration conn = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);
AuthenticationSection section = (AuthenticationSection)conn.SectionGroups.Get("system.web").Sections.Get("authentication");
FormsAuthenticationConfiguration currentForms = section.Forms;
int timeout = currentForms.Timeout.Minutes;
txtAppSessionTimeout.Text = timeout.ToString();
```

Please mark it as correct if you found this answer is correct