# ASP.net MVC global Authorize filter forcing login on an AllowAnonymous action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, forms-authentication

**Setup (using MVC 4)**

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute {

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext) {

        var isAuthorised = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);

        if(isAuthorised) {
            // retrieve authentication ticket from cookie and
            // create custome principal and attach to 
            // httpContext.User
        }

        return isAuthorised;
    }
}
```

Gloabl.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    filters.Add(new MyAuthorizeAttribute());
}
```

HomeController.cs:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Problem**

A call to the home page forces the login page to load.

**Question**

When the HomeController.Index() action is decorated with [AllowAnonymous], why does ASP redirect me to the login view ?

I am using [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/04/18/asp-net-mvc-authentication-global-authentication-and-allow-anonymous.aspx) article for reference

Comment: I just checked with the built-in Authorize and it's working fine for me. May be you have to check with your custom authorize code.

Comment: I've tried with the built-in Authorize attribute, replacing the attribute being added to the global filter in my global.asax but i'm still being redirected to the login page when calling the index action on the home controller. Am I missing something? Some setting in my web config? I have no membership provider, role provider or profile provider configured. Should I have?

Comment: The forms authentication settings in the web.config is the one redirects to the login page. But you don't need to additional settings. I tried by creating a fresh MVC 4 application/Internet template marking the Home controller with Authorize and Index action with AllowAnonymous and it's worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation that everything works as expected Mark. I went back to basics and created a simple internet application and sure enough it does work. It led me to investigate other reasons why. Turns out, the index page was calling Actions on other controllers that returned partial views. I went through every action being called and applied the correct attributes and you are right it does work. Many thanks for your help. Persistence and effort paid off.

Answer (score 11):

As per my comment on the original question. Problem was index view was calling actions on other controllers that returned partial views. Just a case of going through everything and stripping out the old [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: If this solved the problem, mark it as the answer.  You can answer your own questions.

Comment: Great find! I was banging my head against the wall on this one!  Could not figure out why I would "log out" and returning to my home page would automatically take me through the log in process again.  Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Although the original poster has found the cause in his case, I would like to share my resolution, as I came across this question when faced with the same symptoms.

In my web.config file I had, obeying the logic of webforms:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

You must not have this, as it will prevent the request from executing any action without logging in first, except for the login action to which the redirection takes place. I only discovered this when I tried to add a second public action.

Comment: I did the same thing. Discovered when added another public action.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, just helped me out, four years after posting!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem and in the end I've used wrong `AllowAnonymousAttribute` class. There are two AllowAnonymousAttribute classes:

- one from `System.Web.Http` [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.allowanonymousattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)
- another one from  `System.Web.Mvc` [namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowanonymousattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

In your case you have to use of course the one from `System.Web.Mvc` :)

I've spend more then one hour to figure it out in my program

Answer (score -1):

Though this not an answer but..

Try with the built-in `Authorize` code and make sure `AllowAnonymous` is working fine. I see in your custom authorize comments you are trying to

> retrieve authentication ticket from cookie and create custome
>   principal and attach to httpContext.User

I would suggest you do that process very earlier in the `Application_AuthenticateRequest` of `Global.asax.cs` as specified in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273925/how-do-i-implement-custom-principal-and-identity-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: as per my comment above, i've tried using AuthorizeAttribute but still redirecting to login. What gives?