# SimpleMembership password reset hyperlink 401 redirects even with AllowAnonymous

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-areas, simplemembership

I'm attempting to migrate my MVC4 application from ASP.NET Membership to the new SimpleMembership and have run into a snag with password resets.  In my Login view, I have "Forgot Password" hyperlink that does an AJAX post to an action that sends an email with a reset password hyperlink (based loosely on [MSDN guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.generatepasswordresettoken%28v=vs.111%29.aspx)):

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(string userName)
{
    //get the user from database, validate it exists, etc.
    var token = WebSecurity.GeneratePasswordResetToken(userName);
    var resetLink = "<a href='" + Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new {un = userName, rt = token}, "http") + "'>Reset Password</a>";
    //send the email
    return Json(new {result = "Email sent."});
}
```

This works fine, but for some reason when I attempt to use the Reset Password link, I get redirected to the Login screen and Fiddler shows a 401-Unauthorized.  I've tried copy/pasting the link into the browser address bar as well as creating a junk HTML file with the anchor tag in it, but the result is still a 401.  Here's the Reset Password action (also in the Account controller from the MVC4 template):

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string un, string rt)
{
    var model = new ResetPasswordViewModel {UserName = un, ResetToken = rt};
    return View(model);
}
```

I've tried removing the `HttpPost` attribute as well, but that also yields a 401.  What am I missing here?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Steve's comment, I fully-qualified the `HttpPost` attribute and have now realized that it's attempting to post to an area instead of straight to the root `Account` controller.  Using [RouteDebugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/12/routedebugger-2.aspx), I see a resource not found error:

```
Matched Route: {controller}/{action}/{id}
Generated URL: /SiteRoot/Reports/Account/ResetPassword?un=whatever&rt=removedForSecurity using the route "Reports/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Note that it is looking in the `Reports` area.  So, I changed my anchor tag construction in the `ForgotPassword` action, adding the `Area` specification in the route values object, as follows:

```
var resetLink = "<a href='" + Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new {un = userName, rt = token, Area = ""}, "http") + "'>Reset Password</a>";
```

But it's still attempting to use the `Reports` area.  How can I assure that the anchor tag in the email will direct to the site root instead of an area?

**UPDATE 2**
I removed the `HttpPost` attribute, and am now getting the original 401 redirect.

**UPDATE 3**
`ResetPassword` view code:

```
@model Whatever.Web.Models.ResetPasswordViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reset Password";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Reset Password</legend>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User name:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class="disabled-textbox", @readonly="readonly", autocomplete="off" })</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>New Password:</td>
                <td>@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.NewPassword, new { id = "resetPasswordNewPassword" })</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Confirm New Password:</td>
                <td>@Html.Password("resetPasswordConfirmPassword", "", new { id = "resetPasswordConfirmPassword"})</td>
                <td>
                    <div id="passwordsMatch"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit" disabled="disabled"/>
        <div id="resetPasswordResultDiv"></div>
    </fieldset>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#resetPasswordNewPassword, #resetPasswordConfirmPassword").keyup(function() {
            if ($("#resetPasswordNewPassword").val().length > 0 && $("#resetPasswordConfirmPassword").val().length > 0 && $("#resetPasswordNewPassword").val() != $("#resetPasswordConfirmPassword").val()) {
                if ($("#resetPasswordNewPassword").val() != $("#resetPasswordConfirmPassword").val()) {
                    $("#passwordsMatch").html('<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;>Passwords do not match</span>');
                    $("#submitButton").attr('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    $("#submitButton").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            } else {
                $("#passwordsMatch").html('');
                $("#submitButton").attr('disabled', true);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UPDATE 4**
I tried adding another action method to the Account controller that results in a "hello world" style view.  Added `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute, of course.  This method **also** results in a 401 redirect to login.

Comment: There are two AllowAnonmyousAttribute classes. Are you sure you're using the one from `System.Web.Mvc` and not `System.Web.Http` ?

Comment: @Steve - IntelliSense seems to think it's the right one (`System.Web.Mvc`).  I tried fully qualifying it in the attribute `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]` and it gets a resource not found error.  I'll post an update in a minute.

Comment: Also, it looks like you're just creating a link and sending it in an email. What makes you believe you should be using `[HttpPost]` and not `[HttpGet]`?

Also, using `var` is typically bad practice unless you're delcaring anonymous types

Comment: @Steve - I do not agree that using `var` is bad practice unless declaring anonymous types, although I could easily be persuaded if you provide a source.

Comment: I was just clarifying that you can't use it with HttpPost. It wont **ever** hit that action method.

Comment: Does your view have an `Html.RenderAction` which is trying to render an action that does not have the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute? (either on the view, or the _Layout?)

Comment: Nope - edited the OP with the view code.

Comment: @AJ. thanks in advance... could you please share the resetpasswordviewmodel fields that you are using in your example?. Brgds!!

Comment: probably public string ResetToken { get; set; } / public string NewPassword { get; set; } / public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; } ?? brgds!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any problems with the way you've got this set up.  There has to be something else going on here.  Check your _Layout.cshmtl file and assure that you don't have ANY calls to other actions that could be causing the 401.

This person had a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11046666/199913

Comment: OMG, you were right!  I totally forgot that I have a `RenderAction` call in my _Layout file that produces a sidebar menu on every page of the site.  I added `[AllowAnonymous]` to that controller and now it works.  Thank you!!

Comment: I'd chang it to not render the menu (or at least parts of it) when not authenticated but this's the same issue I ran into in my app as well. Contextual information or some sort of pseudo MVC callstack (what controller, action and/or view) is very useful in MVC apps.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure
`Area=""` should be `area=""`

Comment: I removed the HttpPost and, with the new link construction (specifying `area = ""`, lower-case a) I get the same result as I was originally getting: 401 redirect.  I've cleared my cache in all browsers as well.  This is vexing!  Thanks for your continued assistance.

Comment: @AJ I  have no idea, I'm just taking shots in the dark here.