# MVC Windows authentication - authorise(permissions) for entire site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I've seen that the AuthoriseAttribute can work for each individual controller, what i would like to do is set the entire site permissions to one AD group, is that easy to do or should i just copy and paste the authattrib line to each controller?

Thanks

Comment: Add a global filter like the person demonstrates in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033357/asp-net-mvc-global-authorize-filter-forcing-login-on-an-allowanonymous-action

Comment: in the global filter where do i specify what AD groups are allowed to use the site?

Comment: Maybe this article can be useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

Comment: If you have seperate questions you should post them rather then asking in comments. However, since by chance I have this exact code in front of me this morning, what you'll need to do is create a new derived attribute from `AuthorizeAttribute` and override the `OnAuthorization` method to perform your custom logic.

Comment: @VladimirBozic That's a great post, thank you! Im bookmarking it for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @asawyer mentioned using global filter for your case is good practise. For another part of your question in comment: `in the global filter where do i specify what AD groups are allowed to use the site?` you can specify roles in `OnAuthorization` method of your custom authorize attribute, smth like:

```
public class MyAuthAttribute: AuthorizeAttribute
{                
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {  
        Roles = 'ad role1, ad role2...'; //Roles is AuthorizeAttribute member
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and than use it like:

```
GlobalFilterCollection.Add(new MyAuthAttribute());
```

in global.asax or w/e else