# UseCookieAuthentication.LoginPath does not return Identity/Claims in a AD B2C callback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, azure-ad-b2c

I have a legacy MVC App using AD B2C for authentication.  The behavior I want, is to be able to redirect users to my login page instead of the B2C login page.  Once on my login page, I will do some pre-validation and then send the user a challenge.  I have tested the following and the callback of this challenge works and returns Identity/Claims of a user (per example http://bitoftech.net/2016/08/31/integrate-azure-ad-b2c-asp-net-mvc-web-app/comment-page-1/#comment-129447).

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignUpPolicyId));
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ProfilePolicyId));
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId));
```

To achieve a redirect to my login page, I have referenced the following SO, which works EXCEPT I do not get Claims/Identity information in my callback. Reference to SO: [CookieAuthenticationOptions.LoginPath value not used when also using app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685857/cookieauthenticationoptions-loginpath-value-not-used-when-also-using-app-useopen)

Here is my code changes:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignUpPolicyId));
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(ProfilePolicyId));
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(CreateOptionsFromPolicy(SignInPolicyId));

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});
```

**How do I get my claims/identity in my call back?**  Request.IsAuthenticated is also false.  My callback:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Callback() {

var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
IEnumerable<Claim> claims = identity.Claims;
//CLAIMS ONLY HAS NAME AND IS EMPTY - THERE SHOULD BE 18 CLAIMS
return RedirectToAction("Index", "AppIndex");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of what you are trying to achieve, this is not currently possible.

Please refer to the [FAQ for Azure B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs):

> **Can I use my own URLs on my sign-up and sign-in pages that are served by Azure AD B2C? For instance, can I change the URL from
>   login.microsoftonline.com to login.contoso.com?**
>
> Not currently. This feature is on our roadmap. Verifying your domain
>   in the Domains tab in the Azure portal does not accomplish this goal.

You can, however, [upvote the feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334317-customer-owned-domains) and subscribe to Azure User Voice to be notified when this feature is available.