# Asp.net Identity User, Adding First Name and Last Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-identity-2

I have [used this link to add first name and last name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23209868/7936682). Now I'm seeing an error Cannot drop database "dbname" because it is currently in use.. 
I don't want to drop my Database, just want to add first name and last name in register of asp.net identity user in mvc5. give me suggestions..

Comment: It'll be better if you add code to your question.

Comment: Sem, see the link, I have provided, I have followed the same, just to add first name and last name property

Comment: this should not happen. add some code. the structure of your ASPNET users table will help with solving the problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add user First Name and Last Name to an ASP.NET Identity 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209539/how-can-i-add-user-first-name-and-last-name-to-an-asp-net-identity-2)

Comment: @TAHATEMURII I have followed this, because of this implementation, I'm facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

DropCreateDatabaseAlways I was using this option. After changing to

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new 
    MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, 
    APPLICATION.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

This works fine, also I need to enable migration using package manager console

```
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration "FirststName"
Add-Migration "LastName"
```

Thanks @Archana Parmar