# Extension Method on Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, extension-methods, identity

im using MVC 5 and i found this :
[User.Identity.Name full name mvc5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362751/user-identity-name-full-name-mvc5)
, but i dont know how use the  **"Extension Method on Identity"**
where i put this code, and where...please help me

Extension Method on Identity:

```
public static class GenericPrincipalExtensions
{
    public static string FullName(this IPrincipal user)
    {
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = user.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            foreach (var claim in claimsIdentity.Claims)
            {
                if (claim.Type == "FullName")
                    return claim.Value;
            }
            return "";
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: please help me im new on this

Comment: An Extension Method is a static method that looks like it belongs to a class. In this case, you could do something like `objectThatImplementsIPrincipal.FullName()`, which will have the exact same outcome than executing `FullName(objectThatImplementsIPrincipal)`.

I'm afraid you need to read some guides on Extension Methods first.

Comment: on this pages i found the same but i dont know where put the extension method [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362751/user-identity-name-full-name-mvc5),
[link2](http://forums.asp.net/t/1957500.aspx?How%20to%20access%20custom%20Identity%20or%20ApplicationUser%20properties%20)

Comment: The extension method can be anywhere in your solution. It can simply be another file in the project, even sharing the namespace. Did you do some research about them? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new static class, for example *IdentityExtended*
2. Put static method inside it, for example
3. Put the namespaces of Clamis and Principal

`using System.Security.Claims;
 using System.Security.Principal;`

`public static class IdentityExtended
        {
            public static string GetFullName(this IIdentity identity)
            {
                IEnumerable<Claim> claims = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).Claims;
                var FullName = claims.Where(c => c.Type == "FullName").SingleOrDefault();
                return FullName.Value;
            }
        }`

4. Inside View for Example write as below

   `<h1 class="display-4 rainbow-text">Hello, @User.Identity.GetFullName()!</h1>`

   ***Just make sure you put the class inside solution itself no inside a subfolder***