# Set Identity for non web request

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to set identity for a non web request. Currently I am using FormsAuthentication and I am getting user identity via this *User.Identity.Name* . Now I have to make the user login via API. I have the username/password for the user, how can I set the identity for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal

Answer (score 1):

In a non-web environment, the identity is set on the thread and can be accessed by:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity
```

You can use this to manipulate the identity or as Vadim suggested, completely overwrite with your own custom principal.

This code snippet is taken from the `System.Web.Security.Membership` class that works with principals in web and non-web environments and deomstrates how the two can be used together.

```
public static string GetCurrentUserName()
{
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
    {
        HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
        if (current != null)
        {
            return current.User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
    IPrincipal currentPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
    if ((currentPrincipal != null) && (currentPrincipal.Identity != null))
    {
        return currentPrincipal.Identity.Name;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create your own IPrincipal and IIdentity implementations that you then will assign to HttpContext.User after they have been authenticated.

Comment: follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal