# MVC3 and User Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, membership

I'm using the generic membership class and have had my user sign up for workshops.

I need to have something like this

User 1
   --Workshop 1
   --Workshop 2

---

--Workshop 5

User 2
   --Workshop 1
   --Workshop 2

---

--Workshop 5

How do i get the user model?

Comment: Hi there.You might want to re-word your questions as it's not clear what your issues is e.g. what's the "generic membership class"?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you wnat ot extend the standard asp membership user.
If I'm right, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7481582/asp-net-mvc-how-to-extend-account-controller/7481725#7481725) should help you

Comment: I don't want to extend the standard membership. I've used it as it as. What i need is to query users and return workshops they've applied for

Comment: Then you have to extend the model with your custom fields. In the link I gave you, look at the second choice. Then you can access your fields with something similar to Membership.GetAllUser(...) and in your list you should be able to access your fields