# How does ASP.NET Core AuthorizeAttribute work under the hood?

Tags: asp.net-core, authorize-attribute

ASP.NET Core `AuthorizeAttribute` is just a marker containing a little data and no behavior ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authorization/Core/src/AuthorizeAttribute.cs)). Whatever visits the attribute must contain the behavior.

What visits `AuthorizeAttribute` and what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AuthorizeAttribute`  implemented  `IAuthorizeData` interface

```
public class AuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizeData
```

`app.UseAuthorization()` middleware visits  `AuthorizeAttribute` From endpoint metadata  accroding to the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Security/Authorization/Policy/src/AuthorizationMiddleware.cs):

```
var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
......
var authorizeData = endpoint?.Metadata.GetOrderedMetadata<IAuthorizeData>() ?? Array.Empty<IAuthorizeData>();
```

then it could access the scheme,policy,roles you defined when you add the `Authorize` attribute

You could try similar in a middleware:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();
    var authdata = endpoint?.Metadata.GetOrderedMetadata<IAuthorizeData>();
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

Result:

[image]