# .net core service returns as null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have this Has Attribute Class that have Authorize Attr as base class to validate for required permission, i also have a class for permission service which i have a couple of implementations to handle permissions, roles, etc
when i try to use the permission service in the my class it always returns null, i also tried using service scope it also returns as null basically every service i call her ii null, how can i fix it

My HasAttribute Class:

```
public sealed class HasPermissionAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public IPermissionService PermissionService { get; set; }

    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public HasPermissionAttribute(IPermissionService permissionService, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        PermissionService = permissionService;
         _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }
    
    public HasPermissionAttribute(params PermissionKeys[] permissions)
    {   
        var permissionsTitle = permissions.Select(x => x.GetAttributeOfType<DescribePermissionAttribute>().Title);
         Policy = string.Join(",", permissionsTitle);
    }
   
    public HasPermissionAttribute(params SystemModule[] modules)
    {
    //var permissionsTitle = _permissionService.GetModulesPermissions(modules);
        var permissionsTitle = new List<string>();
        foreach (var module in modules)
        {
             var modulePermissions = typeof(PermissionKeys).GetFields()
                 .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<DescribePermissionAttribute>()?.Module == module)
                 .Select(x => x.GetValue(null)).Cast<PermissionKeys>().getPermissionTitle();
    
             permissionsTitle.AddRange(modulePermissions);
        }
        Policy = string.Join(",", permissionsTitle);
        }
        public HasPermissionAttribute(params RolesKey[] roles)
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var permissionService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPermissionService>();
                var permissionsTitle = permissionService.GetRolePermissions(roles);
                Policy = string.Join(",", permissionsTitle);
            }
        }
    }
```

My Service Container :

```
serviceCollection
    .AddScoped<IPermissionService, PermissionService>()
    .AddScoped<HasPermissionAttribute>(s =>
    { 
        return new HasPermissionAttribute(
            s.GetRequiredService<IPermissionService>(),
            s.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>()
        );
    })
```

Comment: This is not the right approach for implementing custom authorization rules - instead of subclassing `AuthorizeAttribute` (and then adding constructors that clearly contain too much heavy-logic) Microsoft recommends using the normal `AuthorizeAttribute` but with Policy Names that then refer to whatever custom authorization logic you want - which is far, far, far more maintainable than jamming things into attribute ctors.

Comment: What is the goal of this? Why does your attribute has so many constructors? Maybe you are looking into something like `IAuthorizationFilter` and using `AuthorizationFilterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices` to resolve the required services?

Comment: `.AddScoped<HasPermissionAttribute>(s =>` <-- Attributes don't work like this... at all...

Comment: @Dai can u explain more ?

Comment: @abdelrhmantarekk There is _no reason_ to register `Attribute` types as DI services.

Comment: @GuruStron at first i only had one constructor and for each controller i was passing the required permissions, i wanted to be able to the pass required system module which contains a set of permissions instead of passing them one by one and also pass the role itself which also refers to a custom set of permissions

Comment: @Dai i wanted to use the methods i implemnted in the permission service, for ex: passing the Role admin to the authorize attribue , in order to get admin permssion list i'll have to use the dbContext which i already injected in the permission service. So that's why i tried to use DI

Comment: @abdelrhmantarekk _"i wanted to use the methods i implemnted in the permission service, for ex: passing the Role admin to the authorize attribue"_ - at any point in time when you were writing the code to do this, you never thought that this felt weird or unnecessary or unnatural? You didn't think it _strange_ to use `Attribute` classes in this way?

Comment: @abdelrhmantarekk _"in order to get admin permssion list i'll have to use the dbContext which i already injected in the permission service. So that's why i tried to use DI" - it sounds like you're building a *dynamic* authorization system that depends on ever-changing permissions/rights in your db instead of having _static_ (not strictly related to the `static` keyword) authorization policies/rules that can only be updated by editing C#, rebuilding, and republishing? If so then you need to use a completely different approach that will probably require you to directly supply Middleware handlers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253559/discussion-between-abdelrhman-tarekk-and-dai).

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid dependency injection in Attribute,there was a similar [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29915192/dependency-injection-in-attributes) for asp.net( not core)

Don't try add any business codes into `[Authorize]` attribute,it just attach `IAuthorizeData` to your endpoint,the auth  codes are in the middleware `app.UseAuthentication(),App.UseAuthorization()`,a [related case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76097059/how-does-asp-net-core-authorizeattribute-work-under-the-hood/76098135#76098135) may help you understand. You could check the source codes of Authorize Attribute and the two middleware above yourself