# Check User Authorization for a Blazor Component (Page) Based on URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, authorization

### What I aim to achieve:

I want to check if the current user has access rights to a specific page in my Blazor application based on the page URL (or Type of Page for that matter).

Also is it possible to get list of all Pages (Blazor components with @page), without implementing my own service to discover them?

Ideally, I'd like to do something like this:

```
var state = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
var hasAccess = (await AuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(state.User, "/myPage")).Succeeded;
```

Is there an existing framework feature or a recommended pattern to handle this scenario or should I implement my custom logic for matching URLs to Page types and then extract the page policy using reflection from the attributes?

I use Blazor components as Pages
example:

```
@page "/myPage"
@attribute [Authorize(Policies.MyPolicy)]
```

Could you please advise if there's an existing method to achieve this within ASP.NET Core, or I will need to develop a custom solution?

Comment: You may try endpoint.Metadata.GetOrderedMetadata<IAuthorizeData>(),this issue may help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76011952/how-to-check-if-current-user-has-permissions-to-use-list-of-controller-actions/76127273#76127273