# Store session info in ASP.Net Cookie or Session State?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I need to store some session related data for a user. This data does not need to be encrypted but I want to ensure the user cannot modify it. I think my options are to store it into a hidden field, store it into a cookie, or store it in ASP.Net session state. I need the solution to be server farm safe.

If its stored in a cookie or hidden field then I need a way to ensure a user can't modify it.

What do you think is the best approach for this sort of data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First question I ask myself about session data: I really need them?
Remember that web is stateless so maybe you can re-engineering your application to not use session state.
Sessions requires a lot of management and server resources.

Meanwhile you have two solutions:

- because you are in a farm put your session on SQL Server configuring session state in web.config (it requires resources and it's a bit slower but is the safest way to store session data to ensure the user cannot modify it)
- add an encryption/decryption mechanism to your cookie with a private server key

Comment: I agree that the first question should be - do I really need to do it this way?  Beyond storing auth information, you should really aim for being as stateless as possible.

Comment: Good answer. An alternative is the AppFabric velocity cache for storing state - see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

A user is always able to modify cookies, because it is **client-side storage**.  You need to store the data **server-side**.

ASP.NET Session State is an acceptable solution for your problem, although there are some caveats regarding server farms.  This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) explains how to make Session State work for your server farm environment.  Be.St.'s answer touches on the suggested out-of-process approach.

A third alternative is to create a database driven session storage that does not necessarily depend on Session state.  I find Session State to be a bit of a hassle with different deployment environments (e.g. server farms), so I will sometimes use this approach.  You can then access this data by attaching a session key to the querystring or storing the session key in the cookie (still potentially modifiable by the user, but less likely to be a target for such action).

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I reckon it's better to store the information in the `cache`, although you could perfectly well store it in the `session` or encrypt it and store it in a `cookie` and it's just a matter of personal preference

The reason I prefer the `cache` is that it is not vulnerable to Session Hijacking, so there is no possible way the user can modify it as it's stored on the server (same as `session` in that respect).

I asked a question about using a custom principal and I included quite a bit of code in there that might help you.

**Code to store extra user information in cache:** [Is this Custom Principal in Base Controller ASP.NET MVC 3 terribly inefficient?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263845/is-this-custom-principal-in-base-controller-asp-net-mvc-3-terribly-inefficient)

**EDIT:** And the reason I prefer to store this information somewhere close at hand is that I don't want to kep nipping off to the database all the time as it is very inefficient to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use a farm and want to share session state among the nodes without going back to the database all the time you could use the [AppFabric Session Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859.aspx). There is a bit of a learning curve setting it up but it does the job and is fast (don't run it on the same box as your application though).