# using custom IPrincipal and IIdentity in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, iprincipal, iidentity, custom-authentication

I create my own `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` implementation as shown below:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Serializable]
public sealed class CustomIdentity : IIdentity {

    private readonly string _name;
    private readonly string _email;
    // and other stuffs

    public CustomIdentity(string name) {
        _name = name.Trim();
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            return;
        _email = (connect to database and read email and other stuffs);
    }

    public string Name {
        get { return _name; }
    }

    public string Email {
        get { return _email; }
    }

    public string AuthenticationType {
        get { return "CustomIdentity"; }
    }

    public bool IsAuthenticated {
        get { return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_name); }
    }

}


[ComVisible(true)]
[Serializable]
public sealed class CustomPrincipal : IPrincipal {

    private readonly CustomIdentity _identity;

    public CustomPrincipal(CustomIdentity identity) {
        _identity = identity;
    }

    public bool IsInRole(string role) {
        return _identity != null && 
               _identity.IsAuthenticated &&
               !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(role) &&
               Roles.IsUserInRole(_identity.Name, role);
    }

    IIdentity IPrincipal.Identity {
        get { return _identity; }
    }

    public CustomIdentity Identity {
        get { return _identity; }
    }

}
```

Also, I create a `HttpModule` and in its `AuthenticateRequest` event, I do this:

```
    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        _application = context;
        _application.AuthenticateRequest += ApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
    }

    private void ApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var formsCookie = _application.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        var identity = formsCookie != null
             ? new CustomIdentity(FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(formsCookie.Value).Name)
             : new CustomIdentity(string.Empty);
        var principal = new CustomPrincipal(identity);
        _application.Context.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
    }
```

Also, I create my own `Controller` and `WebViewPage` like these:

```
public abstract class CustomController : Controller {
    public new CustomPrincipal User {
        get {
            var user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User as CustomPrincipal;
            return user;
        }
    }
}


public abstract class CustomWebViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel> {
    public new CustomPrincipal User {
        get {
            // (Place number 1) here is the error I'm speaking about!!!
            var user = HttpContext.Current.User as CustomPrincipal;
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

as shown in above code, it seems everything is right; But as you can see, in **Place number 1** I can't access the `CustomPrincipal`! Means in this place, I have a `RolePrincipal` instead of having a `CustomPrincipal`. e.g. `HttpContext.Current.User` is a `RolePrincipal` instead of `CustomPrincipal`. But the `RolePrincipal.Identity` property is a `CustomIdentity`!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
_application.AuthenticateRequest += ApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
```

There is a `HttpModule` named `RoleManagerModule` that invokes a method in `HttpApplication.PostAuthenticateRequest` and sets the `HttpContext.Current.User` to `RolePrincipal`. So, you were setting the `User` in `AuthenticateRequest` and the `RoleManagerModule` sets it in `PostAuthenticateRequest`, means after your set, so overrides your settings. Change your `Module.Init`:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
    _application = context;
    // change just this line:
    _application.PostAuthenticateRequest += ApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
}
```

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:**

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11001061/roleprovider-dosnt-work-with-custom-iidentity-and-iprincipal-on-server) -asked by starter again, depended on current question- for a second solution, if this one doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for this answer; I was pulling my hair out trying to figure this one!

Comment: @DavidKeaveny Thank you, but I have to tell you the solution has a problem yet. Search in `king.net`'s questions, you can find a Q associated on this one that there is another problem with IIS, so I suggest a way him/her, that resolve the issue fine. Please look at `king.net`'s questions, you will find it. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up; I'll keep an eye open for the issue when I deploy.