# RoleProvider dosn't work with custom IIdentity and IPrincipal on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httpmodule, roleprovider, iprincipal, iidentity

I'm using a custom `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` in my `ASP.NET MVC` application via `EF 4.3` as expalined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10742259/using-custom-iprincipal-and-iidentity-in-mvc3) (and follow accepted answer's solution). Also, I have a custom `RoleProvider`. **In local (using `IIS Express`), it works currectly**. But now, when I upload the application on a real host, it seems all users are in `"admin"` role! e.g. I create a user that is not in role `"admin"`, but it can access to all protected pages (that need `"admin"` role). e.g. `Role.IsUserInRole` always returns `true`. Have you any idea please? Can you help me? Is there any setting that I should to do in `IIS`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I explain that solution and it works for me. I don't now, may be you should rollback to the `AuthenticateRequest` event.If you want to try this way, you have to remove `RoleManagerModule` completely from your project. Try this and let me know if works or nop:

```
// in your module:

public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
    _application = context;
    // rollback this line:
    _application.AuthenticateRequest += ApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
}

// and in web.config

<!-- in system.web section: -->
</system.web>
  <!-- other stufs -->
  <httpModules>
    <remove name="RoleManager"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>

<!-- and in system.webServer section: -->
<system.webServer>
  <!-- other stufs -->
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="RoleManager"/>
  </modules>
<system.webServer>
```

Comment: will there be any side effects of removing the RolManager module

Comment: @taherchhabra No, if you implement role provider your self. Yes, if you want use the default role provider. For more, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the default RoleManager, it gets difficult. I tried creating my own RoleManager by deriving from the default, without any luck.
After 2 days trying several things, I ended up creating some extension methods for RolePrincipal:

```
public static bool IsEmployee(this RolePrincipal principal)
{
    if (IsAuthenticated())
        return principal.IsInRole("Employee");

    return false;
}

public static bool IsAdmin(this RolePrincipal principal)
{
    if (IsAuthenticated())
        return principal.IsInRole("Admin");

    return false;
}
```

Created a new WebViewPage class:

```
public abstract class BaseViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public virtual new RolePrincipal User
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.User == null)
                return null;

            return (RolePrincipal)base.User; //Hard casting: If it goes wrong, it better goes wrong here
        }
    }
}

public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public virtual new RolePrincipal User
    {
        get
        {
            if (base.User == null)
                return null;

            return (RolePrincipal)base.User; //Hard casting: If it goes wrong, it better goes wrong here
        }
    }
}
```

Modified the web.config in the views folder:

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyCompany.MyProject.BaseViewPage">
```

And all my Controllers derive from my BaseController:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected virtual new RolePrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.User as RolePrincipal; }
    }
}
```

Downside is that the methods query my database everytime they get called.
I'm using MVC 4 btw

Hope this helps anyone