# How to create a CustomPrincipal globally (with and without AuthorizeAttribute)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, iprincipal

I have a custom Principal/Identity for my ASP.NET MVC4 web app. I have also created a AuthorizeAttribute to instantiate my custom principal, assigning it to httpContext.User in controllers where I require Authentication.

This works great for controller/actions that have been decorated with my AuthorizeAttribute, **however, for controllers that don't require authentication (but still use it if it is there), I would like to get my CustomPrincipal (and preferably through HttpContext.User)**.

In these non-decorated controller/actions, HttpContext.User is set, but with a GenericPrincipal rather than with my CustomPrincipal. **Where would the best place to 'override' the default setting of a HttpContext.User to the GenericPrincipal?**

As well, if this is done in every request that has an auth cookie, **how would I then avoid doing the work twice in the case of a AuthorizeAttribute decorated controller** (which would then just become one that mandated authentication).

Just to be clear, my site allows anonymous users access, but on those pages, if one is authenticated (and a CustomPrincipal is realized), there are extra features provided.

I think some of the options are (not certain of my logic behind each one):

- use a session (and handle logic to create what i need here, forgetting about Principals)
- Application_AuthenticateRequest - seen comments around the web that this is old school
- Custom filters set on a base controller
- Create an AuthorizationAttribute on the base controller that lets everyone through and sets up the HttpContext.User as I want it
- IHttpModule - this seems like a descent way (and heading down this path unless others disagree).

Thoughts?

Comment: What's wrong with `AuthenticateRequest`? You just FEEL it's wrong or found a technical issue? I ask this, because I believe the AuthenticateRequest on a custom module is a right way to go.

Comment: Using application_authenticaterequest or a ihttpmodule that hooks into authenticaterequest are essentially equivalent. It is just that modules can be swapped out at runtime, reused etc somewhat easier than a code block in global.asax

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use a global action filter. Let's suppose that you have a custom principal:

```
public class MyPrincipal : GenericPrincipal
{
    public MyPrincipal(IIdentity identity, string[] roles): base(identity, roles)
    {
    }

    ... some custom properties and stuff
}
```

then you could write a global authorization action filter (but which doesn't derive from the base `AuthorizeAttribute` to avoid global authentication, it just implements the `IAuthorizationFilter` interface to ensure that it runs before any other filters):

```
public class GlobalIdentityInjector : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var identity = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity;

        // do some stuff here and assign a custom principal:
        var principal = new MyPrincipal(identity, null);
        // here you can assign some custom property that every user 
        // (even the non-authenticated have)

        // set the custom principal
        filterContext.HttpContext.User = principal;
    }
}
```

The global filter will be registered in `~/App_Start/FilterConfig.cs` so that it is guaranteed that it will apply to all actions:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new GlobalIdentityInjector());
    }
}
```

And now you could have a custom authorization attribute which will be applied only to certain controller actions that require authentication:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // we know that at this stage we have our custom
        // principal injected by the global action filter
        var myPrincipal = (MyPrincipal)httpContext.User;

        // do some additional work here to enrich this custom principal
        // by setting some other properties that apply only to
        // authenticated users

        return true;

    }
}
```

and then you could have 2 types of actions:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var user = (MyPrincipal)User;

    // work with the custom properties that apply only
    // to anonymous users

    ...
}

[MyAuthorize]
public ActionResult Bar()
{
    var user = (MyPrincipal)User;

    // here you can work with all the properties
    // because we know that the custom authorization
    // attribute set them and the global filter set the other properties

    ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent, detailed answer Darin. If only to glean more MVC architecture information from you, could you speak to why you would choose a global action filter vs the other choices?

Comment: The first of your suggestions is out of question because it involves using sessions. Personally I never use sessions. `Application_AuthenticateRequest` is not MVCish. The third and fourth I don't like because of the base controller. And the last one - IHttpModule I don't like because not MVCish. So I choose a global action filter - it doesn't require implementing a base controller (which developers might forget to derive from) and it is universally applied to ALL requests and it is quite common way  to implement such functionality in ASP.NET MVC applications.

Comment: Almost a year later and this saved me immensely.  Thanks a lot Darin.

Answer (score 0):

Overridding Principal in:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Instead of

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

In Global.asax.cs worked for me in an ASP web application