# Storing Additional Information About a Logged In ASP.NET MVC User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, viewdata

I need to store an ID against a user that will be used in EVERY action that is carried out on my web application. I had hoped to use a customized authorization `ActionFilterAttribute` (on an entire controller) to populate the `ViewData` with this additional info, but it turns out that a whole STACK of stuff runs before these `ActionFilterAttributes` do e.g. ModelBinding, Controller construction

I thought perhaps there may be a way to extend the `HttpContext.User.Identity` to store additional data but have no idea even where to start.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
Looking around in more detail on StackOverflow I came across this solution that does EXACTLY what I want and in a super clean and proper way (HINT: It uses the `userData` property of the `FormsAuthenticationCookie` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524305/175893

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have a global (static) [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) and store any additional information regarding the identity/user there - use whatever is convenient as a key... since this dictionary is thread-safe and implemented mostly lock-free it provides excellent performance... this way you don't need to mess around with any ASP.NET-specific stuff...