# How to set custom principal in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, claims-based-identity, iprincipal

I am new to web application. I have created a custom principle and trying to set it in CurrentDomain. This code works perfectly in WPF application. But here it is throwing Policy Exception **"Default principal object cannot be set twice."**

```
 var principal = new CustomPrinciple(currentIdentity);
 Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetThreadPrincipal(Thread.CurrentPrincipal);
```

My CustomPrincple is derived from ClaimsPrinciple

```
  public class CustomPrinciple : ClaimsPrincipal
  { }
```

I am wondering why I am not allowed to set it here. How can I set my custom principle in web application.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC - Set custom IIdentity or IPrincipal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal)

Answer (score 2):

The custom principal should be set the in global.asax file for the request made, not the thread. Then you get hold of the custom principal from [HttpContext.User Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user.aspx)

This answer in this question details the best way to do it: [ASP.NET MVC - Set custom IIdentity or IPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal/10524305#10524305)

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to cal SetDomainPrincipal - instead set Thread.CurrentPrincipal and HttpContext.User

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/08/custom-claims-principals-in-net-4-5/