# MVC Razor Sessionless Authentication and Custom User

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, azure, forms-authentication

I've been learning MVC and am looking at sessionless authentication (for reduced server strain/scaleability and also because AppFabric Cache is expensive on Azure Websites for hosting Session).

My user information is stored in SQL and each user has a Department, Rank, Roles and Permissions (and roles/Depts also have permissions).  I was thinking that all I really need to store is their userId in a secure cookie and if it's not expired fetch the rest of their info with each request in the global.asax. I would secure it with a method such as http://eversystems.eu/Document/15/Sessionless_Authentication_with_Encrypted_Tokens

What I would like to end up with is the ability in my ViewModels to annotate them with custom fields

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")] [Authorize(Dept="IT")] [Authorize(Rank="Manager")]
```

or in the Html say

```
@if(User.IsInDept("IT")
```

or

```
@if(User.HasRank("Manager"))
```

I looked at extending the `FormsAthenticationTicket` and `Membership Provider / Roles` etc and `IPricipal` and `IIdentity` etc but it's difficult to understand exactly how i'd modify them all to achieve what i'm after. The examples i've seen have a lot of extra bloat that I don't want but the best example i've found is by @Ahmad Abu Raddad here [ASP.NET MVC - Set custom IIdentity or IPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal)

If someone could point out if i'm heading in the right direction or possibly suggest alternatives I would appreciate it.

Comment: The best post on this Ive found is Brady Gasters here http://www.bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0 should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks, looks good, will look more in depth tonight.

Comment: Its worth reading the comments at the bottom of that blog post - Ive dropped a few on there myself for hooking up the auth ticket etc ;o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to share how I ended up solving this problem.  I ended up simply creating a custom IPrincipal and exposed my internal database class.

```
 interface ICustomPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    //I pass the whole model across so if we update/modify in the future it will automatically populate the new items for the cookie
    user d { get; set; }
   //some other variables
}
```

I set up a ton of methods in the user class like IsInRole(), isInDept(), HasRank(), HasPermission etc which returned a bool after querying database which gave me the logic in the  view/controller that I needed.

I created a BaseController that could retrieve this new CustomPrincipal

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected virtual new CustomPrincipal User
    {
        get { return HttpContext.User as CustomPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

I also needed to update my WebViewPage so I could retrieve my new CustomPrincipal in the views.

```
public abstract class BaseViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public virtual new CustomPrincipal User
    {
        get { return base.User as CustomPrincipal; }
    }

}
```

and modify my views web.config

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
<host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
<pages pageBaseType="MyNameSpace.BaseViewPage">
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" /> .....
```

If anyone finds this useful but needs more info just pm me

Comment: It would be helpful for others to include when you are creating this custom principal and setting it as the User object on the HttpContext. (`HttpContext.User as CustomPrincipal` would fail if you hadn't yet done this)