# Any examples of a MessageHandler for WebAPI Forms Authentication?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, asp.net-web-api

As a follow-up to this question:

[WebAPI + Forms Authentication + SimpleMembershipProvider using WindowsIdentity when it shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15994857/webapi-forms-authentication-simplemembershipprovider-using-windowsidentity-w)

I'm now trying to implement a message handler that sets the principal on each request, but I'm not sure how to tie this in with simpleMembershipProvider.  I'm looking for an example that sets the principal and performs authentication against simpleMembership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "it depends on the Authentication mechanism you are planning to implement on your web api".

### Basic Http Authentication?

This should work:

http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-message-handlers/

... and it seems there is a better/simpler way

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/10/23/mixing-mvc-forms-authentication-and-web-api-basic-authentication/

The idea here is that you will be sending your credentials in plain text (hopefully you should be using https) and a Message Handler aka DelegatingHandler is going to grab those credentials, validate them using your simple membership provider, and return 401 if invalid or setting up the principal if they are ok.

### More complex mechanisms?

In contrast with the basic http authentication with more complex mechanism your api user is going to authenticate **once** and your api is going to issue a secure token that should be sent on each subsequent requests the client issues.

In this case, your DelegatingHandler would be checking this token, validating it, and respond with a 401 or setting up the Principal accordingly.

Notice that I'm not covering here the logic behind the token issuance or validation because they are usually custom. You can google on how Amazon does it with its api, but I would just use such a complex mechanism if the data behind your api is very sensitive.