# My popup requires re-login

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Good afternoon everyone! I am already logged in to my ASP website that uses C# code behind however, when I go to another page it triggers a popup and the popup wants me to re-login, how do I cause the popup to already be logged in to my session?

am using the following code in page_load to trigger the popup:

```
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "OpenWindow", "window.open('http://website', 'target=_blank');", true);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only checking if !IsPostBack, you also need to check if the Context.User.IsAuthenticated

Which means, Forms Authentification (or other), IIdentity, IPrincipal, and tralala

Check this out
[ASP.NET MVC - Set custom IIdentity or IPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal)