# MVC - User still authenticated after cookie expires

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, asp.net-identity

I have setup my first login system and have followed:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524305

To store some additional data without having to make multiple trips to the database.

The issue I am having is that when the cookie/ticket expires, the user is still seen to be authenticated?

For example:

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
```

authCookie is null, but

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
```

Continues to return true.

Is there a way to force a log out if the cookie has expired?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to replace

> HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

with

```
HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value); 
if(authTicket.Expired) (...)
```

But this does not explain why HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is still set to true. 
I would firstly make sure that my forms authentication and session expiration is set to the same value in the configuration file:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">

<forms cookieless="UseCookies"
             //some configuration + 
             timeout="20">

</forms>

</authentication>

<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
```

Comment: Think iv solved it, there are two separate cookies.
One for the logged in user and one for the extra data.
I had set an expiry on one but not the other.