# Storing user data after authentication with MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am creating a simple login using ASP.NET MVC4 / Razor. I need custom logic, so here's what I have so far:

```
public class User
   {
      [Required]
      [Display(Name = "User name")]
      public string UserName { get; set; }

      [Required]
      [DataType(DataType.Password)]
      [Display(Name = "Password")]
      public string Password { get; set; }

      public int UserID { get; set; }
      public DateTime LastLogin { get; set; }

      public bool IsValid(string username, string password)
      {
         if(MyCustomLogic.isValidUser(username, password)){
            // Set other variables
            return true;
         } else {
            return false;
         }
      }
   }
```

In the Controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(Models.User user)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      if (user.IsValid(user.UserName, user.Password))
      {
         FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, true);
         // This line is in question
      }
   }
   return View(user);
}
```

I want to store the `Model.User` so it can be accessed in the View persistently. Storing it in a `Session` variable seems to obvious choice, but that will expire independently of the `Authentication Cookie`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're asking, how should you store the user for subsequent requests? Convention is to create your own subclass of `IPrincipal` where you can store whatever you want, and set `HttpContext.Current.User` to be an instance of this. [This question has full examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal).

Comment: @JohnSmith That would be blackmail. As I had to infer what you meant from your question, and as it doesn't actually contain a question, I'm not convinced it deserves an upvote.