# MVC 5 custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to implement custom `AuthorizeAttribute`.

I have custom user:

```
    public class MyUser : IPrincipal
    {
        public List<string> Roles { get; set; }
        public IIdentity Identity{ get; set; } 
        public bool IsInRole(string role){ return Roles.Contains(role); }
    }
```

In `global.asax`

```
    protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         MyUser user = new MyUser();
         user.Identity = User.Identity;
         user.Roles = new List<string>();
         user.Roles.Add("MyRole");//I will get them from AD
         HttpContext.Current.User = user;
    }
```

and the Attribute

```
    public class AuthorizeADAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string Roles { get; set; }
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            MyUser user = (MyUser)httpContext.User;//User is not MyUser
            if (user.Roles.Contains(Roles))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(
        AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

The problem is that `httpContext.User` returns `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal`.
Why that happens and how can I access my user from `session_start` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overwrite its value in `Application_PostAuthenticateRequest` event handler in your `Global.asax.cs`.

See this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524305/54937