# Is a Role Provider implementation necessary?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am struggling a little bit to completely understand what is the correct way to implement a windows authentication and role based authorization scheme into an MVC4 application. When the user accesses the (intranet) website I currently have the following method check the user name against the against a database table

```
    List<string> permissionList = 
PermissionBo.GetUserPermissionsList(PermissionBo.ParseUserName(User.Identity.Name));
    Permissions permissions = new Permissions(permissionList);
```

Then the following if state adds a role to a user object:

```
    if (permissions.IsAdmin)
    {
        if(!Roles.RoleExists("UtilitiesToolAdmin"))
        {
            Roles.CreateRole("UtilitiesToolAdmin");
        }
        if(!Roles.IsUserInRole(User.Identity.Name, "UtilitiesToolAdmin"))
        {
            Roles.AddUsersToRole(new string[] { User.Identity.Name }, "UtilitiesToolAdmin");
        }

    }
```

I feel like this may be an incorrect way to go about implementing this, but I am not sure where I am going wrong. Is this sufficient to begin using the authorize attribute like so:

```
[Authorize(Roles="UtilitiesToolAdmin")]
public static void Foo()
{
 return "Bar"
}
```

If not what am I missing?

Comment: Using the Authorize attribute is what you should do. The only time to not use Authorize is if you have to programmatically determine access.

Comment: I will try to clear up my question but I know I want to use the Authorize attribute, however I am unclear if it is "correct" to add roles to a user programmatically like I have done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are doing is simple role checking, a custom Role Provider might be a bit of an overkill (Role Providers also provide facilities for managing the roles themselves).  What you will end up with is a class full of

```
throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Instead, consider creating a custom user principal.  The IPrincipal interface defines an IsInRole method that returns a bool.  This is where you would put your custom role checks.  The advantage of the custom user principal is that now all of the built in ASP.NET role-checking goodies should "just work" as long as you replace the default user principal object with your custom one early enough in the lifecycle.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524305/4004002) has one of the best examples I've seen of using a custom user principal with an MVC application.