# How to get extended profile info of current user without any database trip in asp.net Mvc 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am developing an Asp.Net MVC 5 application using Identity and I am accessing the user name via `User.Identity.Name`.

Normally I use the `UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId())` method, but using this creates an unnecessary database trip on every Action method.

I need to find a method for accessing other user profile info (email, website, city etc.) without a database trip.

I'd be grateful if anyone can help?

Comment: You could make your custom principal and use it. see this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10524305/1433093

Comment: You could also look at Claims to store the additional information [Using Claims in ASP.NET Identity](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com.au/2013/12/using-claims-in-aspnet-identity.html)