# ASP.NET Identity Extend methods to access user properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

As I can extend methods to access user properties?

There are methods like:

```
User.Identity.GetUserId()
User.Identity.GetUserName()
```

Which are accessible from the views and the controllers.

I want to extend this functionality with methods like:

```
User.Identity.GetUserPhoneNumber()
User.Identity.GetUserLanguaje()
```

Comment: You could create custom class which inherits from IIdentity or IPrincipal in order to store your new properties. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Similar Question: [Need access more user properties in User.Indentity](http://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2263) answered by Microsoft professionals at codeplex worklog as below

> "You can get the User object and do User.Email or User.PhoneNumber since these properties are hanging off the User model"

**We can get the application current User object in ASP.Net identity as below**, from there you can access all properties of user object, we follow the same in mvc5 web-apps as of now.

```
//In Account controller like this
var currentUser = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

In other controllers you will need to add the following to your controller:

```
  var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));

  // Get the current logged in User and look up the user in ASP.NET Identity
  var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Now we can access all user props(Phone# and Language) as below

```
var phoneNumber = currentUser.PhoneNumber;
var userLanguage = currentUser.Language;
```

**EDIT:** If you want to retrieve the same in any view.cshtml or _Layout.cshtml then you should do like below

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
@using YourWebApplication.Models

@{
    var phoneNumber= string.Empty;
    var userLanguage = string.Empty;
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
        var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        phoneNumber = currentUser.PhoneNumber;
        userLanguage = currentUser.Language;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Estoy tratando de poner estos datos en _Layout.cshtml,  would be right to do the following , or is it better to use session variables? @{
    var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
    var currentUser = manager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
}

Comment: Updated Question see last EDIT section

Comment: Is there any kind of overhead in retrieving the user?  I mean unless it somehow caches it, wouldn't it be going to the DB every time?

Comment: Yes there is overhead! Recommendation: Prepare user view-model object with all related props and put it in his session. In specific cases user session object can be refreshed from UserManager/Database.

Comment: And what about adhering to DRY? Do we REALLY need to write this code in all methods that we want to retrieve user information?

Comment: Its better to put them in a separate method, and call the method where ever you need.