# How to claim role from JWT using razor view ASP .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, jwt, token, roles

Hello I am working on JWT token and trying to claim role using razor view using Asp .net core. For that I tried to use the following code.

```
@{ 
var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var tokenContent = jwtHandler.ReadToken(tokenModel.Result) as JwtSecurityToken;
var role = tokenContent.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "Role").Value;
var email = tokenContent.Claims.First(claim => claim.Type == "email").Value;
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
the type or namespace name 'jwtsecuritytokenhandler' could not be found
```

How can I claim role using razor view?

Comment: check if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139068/get-asp-net-identity-current-user-in-view

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` dll in the `NuGet Packages`.

Then add namespace:

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
```