# Get ApplicationUser from Partial View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-core-mvc

I have asked similar question about older MVC version and Membership, but those solutions don't work with Idendity and MVC 6. 
I want to display user's first name inside _LoginPartial.cshtml file. So, instead of `"Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!"` I want to access ApplicationUser.FirstName for the currently logged in user. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another solution, [implementing custom IPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal). I think it's the best, cause it doesn't require user search every time I need that info.

Answer (score 3):

I present a solution in my opinion better because it requires only one search for profile per request.

**First: Create a user service**

```
public interface IUserProfileLoader
{
    Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentApplicationUser(ClaimsPrincipal user);
}

public class UserServices : IUserProfileLoader
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private ApplicationUser _CurrentUser;
    public UserServices([FromServices]UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    public async Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentApplicationUser(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        if (_CurrentUser == null)
        {
            _CurrentUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(user.GetUserId());
        }
        return _CurrentUser;
    }
}
```

**Then register the service**

In *ConfigureServices* add the following:

```
// Add user profile services.
services.AddScoped<IUserProfileLoader, UserServices>();
```

**For use in a View**

Inject the service:

```
@inject IUserProfileLoader UserServices
```

then access property like this:

```
@((await UserServices.GetCurrentApplicationUser(User)).Email)
```

**For use elsewhere...**

You can access the service in an *Action* (for example) using:

```
[FromServices]IUserProfileLoader UserServices
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For a much simpler fix, you can inject services directly into your view to retrieve the `ApplicationUser`.

```
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> MyManager

@{
    var applicationUser = MyManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());
}
```

Also note you can add the `@inject` in your `_ViewStart.cshtml` if you want access to your `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` from all of your views.

Comment: yeah, it seems simpler. wouldn't it be better to just save the current app user after the log in?

Comment: Not sure what you mean when you say "save the current app user".

Comment: well, save the needed information so the app won't use database everytime it needs to show user's name

Comment: Oh of course, I was simply showing that if you were to do that approach instead of wrapping bits in view components etc. you can just pull in your own service that manages users into your page.

Comment: GetUserId() is not an Identity method. You can do User.Identity.Name.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this solution using components, but it seems like an overkill.
**Views\Shared_LoginPartial.cshtml**

```
...
@await Component.InvokeAsync("FirstName", User.Identity.GetUserId())
...
```

**Views\Shared\Components\FirstName\Default.cshtml**

```
@model Models.ApplicationUser

@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + Model.FirstName + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

**ViewComponents\FirstNameViewComponent.cs**

```
public class FirstNameViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly IUserService m_userService;

    public FirstNameViewComponent(IUserService userService)
    {
        m_userService = userService;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(string userId)
    {
        Models.ApplicationUser user = await m_userService.FindUserByIdAsync(userId);
        return View(user);
    }
}
```

**Services\UserService.cs**

```
public interface IUserService
{
    Task<ApplicationUser> FindUserByIdAsync(string id);
}

public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> m_userManager;

    public UserService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        m_userManager = userManager;
    }

    public Task<ApplicationUser> FindUserByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        return m_userManager.FindByIdAsync(id);
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
...
services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
...
```

I guess I can update the user service and store ApplicationUser after log in, and removed it after log off, but I wonder if there is another way to solve this. Also I'm not sure if scoped service is the best here, I didn't find a way to make it session, not request scoped.