# MVC 5 seeding users only works for email

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am working on a porject built on MVC5 and EF Code First.

I have multiple contexts, but the one I'm concered about here is the **ApplicationDbContext** which has the following configuration code:

```
namespace DX.DAL.Migrations.ApplicationDbMigrations
{

    public class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            MigrationsDirectory = @"Migrations\ApplicationDbMigrations";
            ContextKey = "DX.DAL.Context.ApplicationDbContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

            if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
            {
                roleManager.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));
            }

            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "John", Email = "j.doe@world.com" };


            if (userManager.FindByName("John") != null) return;

            var result = userManager.Create(user, "Password123@");

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try and login with the email and password seeded above, I get the error:

> **Invalid login attempt**

I wrote the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM AspNetUsers
```

And I see the following:

[image: record]

So the seed has been created. But why can't I login?

Also, I know that if I change the Username to be the same as the email, then it works and I can login. Must the username and email be the same for ASP.NET Membership in MVC 5 to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so many different things, I went with LukeP's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal).

I left Identity as it is and just added a new property called `DisplayUsername` and allowed the user to set that up on registration.