# ASP.NET MVC 5 Pass/Get more user data to the whole application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, claims-based-identity

I've added a few new columns to User model which inherited from IdentityUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    public int Age { get; set; }
    public bool Sex { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        ClaimsIdentity userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        //userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("age", this.Age.ToString()));

        return userIdentity;
    }

}
```

By default I can only get user name, like shown in _LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

I'd like get custom info from User.Identity like Age and Sex, for example. I find the solutions around pretty weird to implement and using claim I couldn't make it global once I'm gonna display it in every page.

If the way to do it is by adding claims like this:

```
userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("age", this.Age.ToString()));
```

How can I get it easily in a View?

Comment: This may be of help [Custom Identity & Principal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal)

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to user session cookies, so in AccountController.cs I add two lines in the  ***case SignInStatus.Success***:

```
var user = SignInManager.UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
Session["userInfo"] = user.Age;
```

Then I can call in the _LoginPartial.cshtml for example:

```
 @{
    if (Session["userInfo"] != null)
    {
        var age = Session["userInfo"];
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Age: " + age.ToString(), "Index", "Albums")</li>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This pulls from **WebpageRenderingBase**, which has an **IPrincipal** User property.

IPrincipal defines an Identity property which gives access to an item which is of a type that implements the interface **IIdentity**.

**So, what you'd be hoping is that the @User.Identity IIndentity returned might actually be an ApplicationUser, and if it is, then you could cast it to such and then access the additional properties.**

If that is true, then you're already done.  If it's not, then you'll need to first obtain an ApplicationUser by some other means.

So the big question is: What actual **type** is the item which implements the IIdentity interface, for which you already have?

```
@if( User.Identity is ApplicationUser)
{
  <text>
    @(((ApplicationUser)User.Identity).Age)
  </text>
}
else 
{
  //GoFish
}
```