# Mvc, Authorize bounces authorized users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication, owin

I'm trying to make a section of a MVC 5 webpage restricted to users of a certain Active directory group, however the [Authorize] attribute (on controller) blocks logged in users aswell.

My Login page code behind looks as follows:

```
public class AccountController: Controller
{

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    // POST: /Account/Login
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ActiveDirectoryHelper ad = new ActiveDirectoryHelper();

            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                if (ad.CheckGroupMembership(model.UserName))
                {
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                    {
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Credentials are correct but you are no authorised \n You Need membership in group: HKF-HIT-FortigateAPI-GS");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect");
            }
        }
        // if we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
    // POST: /Account/LogOff
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
public class ActiveDirectoryHelper
{
    string group = "HKF-HIT-FortigateAPI-GS";
     public bool CheckGroupMembership(string name)
    {
        var context = new PrincipalContext(
                            ContextType.Domain,
                            "AD-Domain", @"Username", "Password");

        var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                            context,
                            IdentityType.SamAccountName,
                            name);

        var test = userPrincipal;

        if (userPrincipal.IsMemberOf(context,
             IdentityType.Name,
             group))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The user passes and is redirected to Index in Home controller.

This controller however has the [Authorized] value set as follows:

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And here the user in bounced back to the loginpage, as if he was not Authorized.

Also this is web.config:

In the browser i can see the ADAuthCookie.

Edit: Ading pictures of Request data:

Account Post:

[image]

Fiddler:

[image]

Index Get:

[image]

Fiddler:

[image]

EDIT: Question has been solved, after going trough the amazing guide linked by in the comments i realised i was never handling my cooke in the Global.asaz.cs Class.

Adding an overide to Application_PostAuthenticateRequest solved my problem.

The code i added ended up using:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<CustomPrincipalSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);

        CustomPrincipal newUser = new CustomPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
        newUser.Name = serializeModel.Name;
        HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
    }
}
```

In global.asax and i also added:

```
CustomPrincipalSerializeModel serializeModel = new CustomPrincipalSerializeModel();
serializeModel.Name = model.UserName;

JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string userData = serializer.Serialize(serializeModel);

FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
         1,
         model.UserName,
         DateTime.Now,
         DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
         false,
         userData);

string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
```

To my login page.

Comment: Have you debugged the http session with an http debugger like Fiddler? Are you sure the cookie is there and is passed together with the request to the home/index?

Comment: I added fiddler and visual studio output of /account/login post and of following  /Home/index Get results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AuthorizeAttribute` [checks the `HttpContext.User` value (an `IPrincipal` implementation) and the `HttpContext.User.Identity` value (an `IIdentity` implementation)](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs#L54-L65).

All of the security frameworks (Identity, Membership, etc.) from Microsoft use these interfaces to communicate with MVC/ASP.NET. If you are using a custom security framework, you also need to implement these interfaces and set them in the `AcquireRequestState` (if using session state)  or `PostAuthorizeRequest` event.

See [ASP.NET MVC - Set custom IIdentity or IPrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524305/181087) for an example of the latter along with custom `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` implementations.