# Authenticating html pages

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

One of our client using some tool to generate the html pages and basic authentication enabled for the all the websites. We need to create IIS user/password for every website.

Now the requirement is to move away from basic authentication and build a tool to generate username/password themselves and store in the database but still they want to use html pages for their websites.

We are thinking to build a ASP.NET MVC login page with the Form authentication but not sure how to integrate the html pages with the website. Users should be redirected to Html pages after the authentication but how to authenticate if user access the html pages directly without credentials?

Thanks

Comment: view this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

```
if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  //your code
}
```