# Cookies not showing up in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, windows-10

I'm using cookies to pass user information for authentication as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal?rq=1). Everything was working fine, until our team upgraded our computers and are now on windows 10. Now my cookie is not found in global.asax.cs's Application_PostAuthenticateRequest.

Here's my code trying to send the cookie:

```
private void AddUserDataToCookies(User user)
    {
        var serializeModel = new WebUserSerializeModel
        {
            FirstName = user.Person.FirstName,
            MiddleName = user.Person.MiddleName,
            LastName = user.Person.LastName,
            CredentialNumber = user.CredentialNumber,
            Roles = user.Roles.Select(role => role.Name).ToList(),
            Permissions = user.Permissions.Select(perm => perm.PrimaryKey).ToList()
        };

        var userData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(serializeModel);
        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.CredentialNumber, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15), false, userData);
        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
        {
            Secure = true,
            HttpOnly = true
        };

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
    }
```

The cookie shows up in request cookie. But when I try in my global.asax, it doesn't. My global asax code is below.

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var cookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (cookie != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

                if (authTicket != null)
                {
                    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    var serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<WebUserSerializeModel>(authTicket.UserData);

                    var user = new WebUser(serializeModel.FirstName, serializeModel.LastName)
                    {
                        MiddleName = serializeModel.MiddleName,
                        CredentialNumber = serializeModel.CredentialNumber,
                        Roles = serializeModel.Roles,
                        Permissions = serializeModel.Permissions
                    };

                    HttpContext.Current.User = user;
                }
            }
            catch (CryptographicException ex)
            {
                Logger.Error("Error while decrypting cookie post authentication.", ex);
                FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                HttpContext.Current.User = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Does anyone have any ideas why changing to Windows 10 may have causes this issue? I'm somewhat new to ASP.NET and web development in general.

EDIT - by removing Secure = true when creating my cookie I was able to get it to work. I'm investigating why this is the case before I add an answer and I welcome any insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my edit, the problem was that Secure was set to true when creating my cookie but I did not have SSL enabled when running locally, unlike, I guess, on my old workstation. The code in my controller currently looks like:

```
private void AddUserDataToCookies(User user)
    {
        var serializeModel = new WebUserSerializeModel
        {
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            MiddleName = user.MiddleName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            CredentialNumber = user.CredentialNumber,
            Roles = user.Roles,
            Permissions = user.Permissions
        };

        var userData = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(serializeModel);
        var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, user.CredentialNumber, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Minutes), false, userData, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket)
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Secure = true
        };

        if (Request.IsLocal)
        {
            cookie.Secure = false;
        }

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

Leaving Request.IsLocal is a bit ugly but it's good enough for now until we decide if we want to implement SSL for everyone locally.

At least it was an easy fix.