# ASP.NET MVC 5 windows authentication with custom properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC web application which is using Windows authentication. I can use `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` to get the users username.

I need to be able to store and access additional fields for example full name, telephone etc. I don't have access to Active Directory. I was planning on creating a simple table in the database with with the Windows username and the additional fields as columns.

What is the correct/recommended way to implement this? I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
HttpContext.User.Identity.Telephone
```

Comment: you may need to create a model user class with all the additional column and derived it from IdentityUser Class

Comment: First of all, AD has far more complex model than SAM. Phone nember is not in SAM. Anyway the IPrincipal built during NTLM negotiation is minimalustic - such properties are not fetched for performance reasons. So, you need to fetch them for yourself based on the username.

Comment: Please check [This Stakeoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064271/asp-net-mvc-set-custom-iidentity-or-iprincipal)